# What are the best Crawl Rules anybody would recommend on a Prod 2013 environement

Tags: enterprise-search

I would like to ask the experts what are the query rules they recommend to put up to filter the Junk data from getting crawled, please recommend.

I have used the following

/list/publishedfeed 
/sites/forms/
/siteassets
/formservertemplates

Answer (score 2):

It's depend upon you company policy, one thing is important  to one company but same thing is not for other.

you can create crawl rules for the following reasons:

- To avoid crawling irrelevant content by excluding one or more URLs.
- to relevant content
  useful for sites that do not contain relevant content but have links to relevant content.

By default, the crawler will not follow complex URLs, which are URLs that contain a question mark followed by additional parameters — for example, http://contoso/page.aspx?x=y. If you enable the crawler to follow complex URLs, this can cause the crawler to gather many more URLs than is expected or appropriate. This can cause the crawler to gather unnecessary links, fill the crawl database with redundant links, and result in an index that is unnecessarily large

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn535606.aspx#BKMK_UseCrawlRules